# aurelia Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/main.ts

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In order to learn Aurelia, I'm just following the [quickstart](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest) tutorial of Aurelia.js framework with `basic-aurelia-project` example but I got this error in the console at the first attempt to render `Todos`:

```
Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/main.ts
    Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/main.ts
```

I looked at the src files but could not figure out where this `main.ts` should come from.
It's really furstrating as the firs step. What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: The `basic-aurelia-project` starter solution itself indeed produces the above error. You'll have to read a bit further, create the `main.ts` file and also an `app.ts` file which serves as root component.

Comment: But it states that `When you run the app, you should see the app render out the heading property, something like this: *Todos*`. That's what perplexed me.

Comment: Also, i don't see anywhere in the tutorial that creating a `main.ts` is mentioned.

Comment: [Here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/5) is the step which involves creating the `main.ts` file

Comment: But that is `main.Js`!

Comment: You can also select `TypeScript`. Click the `esnext` dropdown item. Be aware you'll need the corresponding typescript defenition file. You can get it by installing `aurelia-framework` from `npm`.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by `dropdown item`. I use `http-server -o -c-1` to serve the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135596/discussion-between-dieterg-and-karlom).

Comment: In the upper right hand corner of each code listing, there is a drop down that can be used to select which language you want to use. It's next to the word "Copy."

Answer (score 6):

I was following the same tutorial as Karlom, and got the same error when starting up http-server -o -c-1. 
"GET /src/main.ts" Error (404): "Not found"

The tutorial is using javascript, but when the application starts up the server looks for main.ts not main.js.

in index.html change
src="scripts/config-typescript.js" to src="scripts/config-esnext.js"